# Conditionally include text between multiple values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have this, which works, but some fields don't always have values (& don't render). Is there a way to include text conditionally? For example, between {a}, {b} & {c}, but only if they are both rendered?

```
const yay = `${a ? a + ` | `: ""}${b ? b + ` | ` : ""}${c ? c : ""}`
```

Comment: can you please provide what you want to achieve? Like sample output so i can help.

Comment: Hi @DhavalR , I'm essentially wanting to output something like "A | B | C"; but only between each item if an item exists before and after it. Does that help any? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all of them in an array and filter them based on their *truthy* value evaluation in javascript. Later, just join the result as a string delimited by `|`.

```js
let a = "789";
let b = "";
let c = true;

const result = [a,b,c].filter(ele => ele);

console.log(result.join('|'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this; how would I render this in a view, though?

Comment: @anonymoose Like `<p>{result.join('|')}</p>`

Comment: @anonymoose If any of the answers helped you with your issue(not necessarily mine), then can you accept it? It lets future researchers know that there exists a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[a, b, c].filter(v => !!v).join('|')`.  This filters out all falsy values (undefined, null, false, 0, empty string, etc), which is what your current code is doing as well.

Comment: That sounds nice, thank you. How would I render this in a view, though?

Comment: not sure exactly what you're after, if you could add an example of what you're going for in the question I might be able to help